# Private Route function code to be converted to ES6 class version for react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi I have this file that i copied from a tutorial and I would like to convert it to ES6 class notation but I don't understand the syntax of the function declaration.

```js
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest })
```

This is the full code. The reason i want to change it is that i want to use react-redux connect HOC and I can get my head around how to do it with it's current syntax.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./context/auth";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { authTokens } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authTokens ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { referer: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I want something like this but i know this is not correct.

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.authTokens) {
      return <Route>{this.props.children}</Route>;
    } else {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { referer: this.props.location } }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    authTokens: state.authTokens,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the functional component not work? Why would you go backwards to a class-based component? Have you already tried and something isn't working? What is the issue you have? Looks like you forgot to spread the rest of the props into `Route`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess looking at the code I think you forgot to spread the rest of the props into the `Route` component. This is so the `path` and other props make it through to the `Route` component.

```
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { authTokens, children, location, ...rest } = this.props;
    if (authTokens) {
      return <Route {...rest}>{children}</Route>;
    } else {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { referer: location } }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

> I don't understand the syntax of the function declaration.
>
> `function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest })`

All react components receive a single `props` argument. Often times functional components use object destructuring assignment to declare the prop variables used right in the function signature. The spread syntax (`...`) takes the rest of the passed props and assigns them to a new variable as well. `...rest` creates an object named `rest` that we can then pass on to children components.

The above is equivalent to

```
function PrivateRoute(props) {
  const { component: Component, ...rest } = props;
```

1. `component` is destructured and renamed to `Component`
2. The rest of the props are spread into a new object `rest`

Comment: Thank you I can't test this right now because i have other errors where the state is not updated by react-redux in my application but this has helped me understand how to convert from functional to ES6 class. I will update as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I like the ES6 syntax better as I am a java developer and more familiar with the class syntax. Also not sure how to wrap a function in react-redux connect. My app has errors that are unrelated to this solution so I created a dummy application to test your answer and it is working correctly. Thanks again.